# Looping seems to not follow sequence

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here!

```
seq = {'a': ['1'], 'aa': ['2'], 'aaa': ['3'], 'aaaa': ['4'], 'aaaaa': ['5']}
for s in seq:
    print(s)
```

outputs:

```
a
aa
aaaa
aaaaa
aaa
```

Whereas surely it should output:

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575819/sorting-a-dictionary-in-python

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Dictionaries are not ordered. If you need to rely on the ordering, you need an OrderedDict - there's one in the `collections` module in Python 2.7, or you can use one of the many recipes around.

Comment: You also may want to point out that an OrderedDict is not a sorted dictionary.  An OrderedDict merely preserves the order in which keys were added.

Answer (score 5):

Standard Python dictionaries are not ordered: there is no guarantee on which order the keys will be returned.

If you want your keys returned in the order *in which you create keys* you can use an [`OrderedDict` from `collections`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Alternatively, if you want your output sorted on the *values of the keys* the following would do:

```
for s in sorted(seq):
    print s
```

Comment: also easy to sort by the length of the keys `for s in sorted(seq, key=len):` (same order in this case though)

Answer (score 1):

why you don't do (**dictionary are not ordered**):

```
for s in range(5):
    print 'a'*s
```

**Edit :** ok as you which :)

the thing is in the expression : `'a'*s` which mean create a new string which contain s time 'a'.

in the python interpreter you can play with it (isn't python wonderful :) )

```
>>> print 'a'*2
aa
>>> print 'a'*3
aaa
```

PS: if you're new to python i will suggest that you use [ipython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) if you don't use it yet.

Comment: for s in range(1,len(seq)):
 print 'a'*s

Comment: btw could you break that down a little for me, i'm new to python & don't understand the 'a'*s bit.

Comment: @significance: If you multiply a string by an integer in python, the string gets repeated that many times (this works for any sequence in python).

Comment: lol - yeah just worked that out, not exactly what i was looking for!