# Methods for sorting a dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am referring to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/575889/292291

1. If I use integers as the key, it appears I am guaranteed a sorted order?

   ```
   >>> dict = { 2: "list 2", 0: "list 0", 1: "list 1" }
   >>> dict
   {0: 'list 0', 1: 'list 1', 2: 'list 2'}
   ```
2. In `sorted(mydict, key=lambda key: mydict[key])`, how do I interpret or read the lambda? I don't understand that part since I'm new to lambdas. What does `key:` and `mydict[key]` refer to?
3. In `sorted(d, key=d.get)` what does `d.get` refer to? If I do:

   ```
   >>> dict.get
   <built-in method get of dict object at 0x1d27830>
   ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- Dicts never guarantee an order, sometimes it may even look like it does, but get enough numbers in there and you'll see they don't (this is because of the way that [hashes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Hash_function) are obtained for each key)

2- These two are the same:

```
lambda key: mydict[key]

def temp_function(key):
    return mydict[key]
```

Basically, you are creating a temporary function that receives **key** as a parameter, and returns **mydict[key]**

3- The second argument of **sorted** refers to the function that will be called, passing the current dict key. The value returned by this will be used to determine the order of your sorted dict.

Comment: As @wim said, if you want an ordered dict, use **OrderedDict**

Answer (score 4):

1. No. Dictionaries are ordered by the hash of their keys, and there is no guarantee that the hash algorithm won't change between versions or implementations.
2. Everything between `lambda` and `:` is the arguments. Everything after the `:` is the returned expression.
3. The `get` method of the object bound to `d`. In `dict` objects it returns the value if the key exists, otherwise the passed default or `None`.

Comment: 2. where do the argument `key` come from?

Comment: The arguments can have any names you like. Replacing "key" with "aswgfawe" would make no difference, same as with normal functions.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, please avoid calling a variable `dict`, for you can shadow the built-in this way.

1) I don't believe so.  If you want sorted dict, just use `OrderedDict` from `collections` module.

2) You should read it as an anonymous function, which given an input argument `key`, will return the object `mydict[key]`.  It would be equivalent to:

```
def foo(key):
  # assume mydict is in scope
  return mydict[key]
```

3) Assuming your variable `d` here is a dict, it will return a list of *keys* in the dictionary sorted by their corresponding *values* from `d`.  It means that the function `d.get()` is called for whatever is `in d` when iterating, and the list will be sorted by the return values of `d.get` rather than by the objects themselves.