# Printing elements related to information in 'dict'

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

Having a little trouble understanding "`dict[]`" command, if anyone could help me with this, it would be much appreciated.

This is the code I have so far: (I've put in where and what I need help with)
    import csv

```
inputYear = input('Please enter the year: ')
inFile = open('babyQldAll.csv', 'rU')
cvsFile = csv.reader(inFile, delimiter=',')

dict = {}

for row in  cvsFile:
    year, name, count, gender = row

if (year == inputYear) and (gender == 'Boy'):
    dict[name] =  count

print('Popular boy names in year %s are:' % inputYear)


# According to information in 'dict',  print (name, count) sorted by 'name' in alphabetical order         



print("Print boy names... ")    


inFile.close()
```

using the code above I'm trying to get an outcome of:

```
Popular boy names in year "2010" are: Aidan 119, Alex 224, Derek 143, Steven 212, Tom 111.....
```

from the following input:

```
File 2010:
2010, Steven, 212, Boy
2010, Mary, 423, Girl
2010 , Tom, 111, Boy
2010, Jessica, 223, Girl
(and so on)
```

Comment: Tip: don't use `dict` as a name for things, since that shadows the buildin `dict()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import csv
import sys

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    input = raw_input

input_gender = 'Boy'  # could make this a user-supplied value too

input_year = input('Please enter the year: ').strip()
file_name = 'babyQldAll.csv'

with open(file_name) as fobj:
    csv_file = csv.reader(fobj)
    name_counts = {}
    for row in csv_file:
        year, name, count, gender = (entry.strip() for entry in row)
        if year == input_year and gender == input_gender:
            name_counts[name] = int(count)

print('Popular {} names in year {} are:'.format(input_gender.lower(), input_year))
for name, count in name_counts.items():
    print(name, count)

print('\nBoys names in alphabetical order:')
for name in sorted(name_counts.keys()):
    print(name)

print('\nBoys names in alphabetical order and counts:')
for name, count in sorted(name_counts.items()):
    print('{}: {}'.format(name, count))
```

Some notes:

1. In Python 2 you should use `raw_input`, which turned into `input` in 
   Python 3. One way would to make your program work in same way in Python 2
   and 3 would adding this to the beginning of your file:

   ```
   import sys

   if sys.version_info.major < 3:
       input = raw_input
   ```

   Now you can use `input` no matter what Python version.
2. Your input has a space after the comma. Since the csv reader only
   looks for commas, the space is part of the string in your list
   for a row. Stripping it off with `(entry.strip() for entry in row)` solves
   this.
3. So fare I compare a string for the year. I might be worthwhile to convert
   both, `input_year` and `year` to and `int` and compare these.

Running th Program with the example file in the question looks like thi:

```
Please enter the year: 2010
Popular boy names in year 2010 are:
Tom 111
Steven 212

Boys names in alphabetical order:
Steven
Tom

Boys names in alphabetical order and counts:
Steven: 212
Tom: 111
```

Comment: Would it be possible to order the boy names with the counts beside?

Comment: @RelientFX Added sorted names with counts.

Comment: All the counts come up as 67?

Comment: I added sample output to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`dict[]` is used to retrieve values stored in the dictionary using the key. Therefore, if you had the above stored as:

```
names = {'Steven': [212, 'Boy', 2010], 'Mary': [423, 'Girl', 2010]}
```

And wanted to retrieve Steven's information, you would say `names['Steven']`, which would return the list `[212, 'Boy', 2010]`.

I don't think this will fully answer your question, but it should help you get started. You may also want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575819/sorting-dictionary-keys-in-python) if you want to pre-sort your dictionary.

Comment: So for the code that I've posted above what would you recommend is the best way to get that outcome?