# python, read keys from dict by size, to plot them

Tags: python, dictionary, sorteddictionary

I have a python dict which contains unsorted key/value pairs, where the key is a datetime and the value is an int.

```
{"1.12.2015":5, "4.12.2015":3, "2.12.2015":6, ...}
```

I now wish to read the keys, and their values sorted by date in order to plot them using pyplot.

The result should be like:

```
first pair:
1.12.2015 : 5
second: 
2.12.2015 : 6
third:
4.12.2015 : 3
```

the question is, what is the best way to get the dates and values out in the right order. It would be best if there was an option which runs in python 2.6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting dictionary keys in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575819/sorting-dictionary-keys-in-python)

Comment: @Dylan Lawrence this shows sorting by values, but i wish to sort by key, or can this be achived the same way?

Comment: Please see answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this more or less what you are looking for?

```
data = {"1.12.2015":5, "4.12.2015":3, "2.12.2015":6}

from datetime import datetime

for k,v in sorted([(datetime.strptime(k, '%d.%m.%Y'), v) for k,v in data.iteritems()]):
    print datetime.strftime(k, '%d.%m.%Y'), v
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for, ty

Comment: this creates a list for no reason, casts to datetime objects and then calls datetime.strftime to create a string again, I really don't follow the logic

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham the for-loop + sorted method is what i was looking for. Since the dates are stored as datetime objects i don't need to cast them like in this example which makes the actual implementation a lot cleaner.

Comment: @mat, then you just need `sorted(d)` or `sorted(d.items())`, there is no reason to first create a list or call datetime.strftime, if you were doing anything you would call strftime on the datetime object or call one of the various methods to get a string representation

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: You are right. However, note that in older Pythons `d.items()` would create an intermediate list. Another intermediate list is created by `sorted()` under covers. Hence, there's a whole bunch of intermediate lists being created behind the scenes, and it is not obvious that the list comprehension version is somehow less efficient.

The particular syntax (list comprehension around an iteritems) was chosen because this seemed as the most "flexible" form for an example to build upon. Your version is certainly more concise.

Comment: You could still  `sorted((datetime.strptime(k, '%d.%m.%Y'), v) for k,v in data.iteritems())` at worst, I was more referring to converting to datetime objects and then calling `datetime.strftime` to convert back to strings.  If you wanted to use strftime you would usually call it  on the object but `str(dt_object)` would also do the same

Comment: I happen to use `strftime` so rarely (i.e. never) I did not come to think the datetime object has it as a method :)

Answer (score 4):

Use a lambda as the key to sorted casting each key to a datetime object:

```
 from datetime import datetime

d = {"1.12.2015": 5, "4.12.2015": 3, "2.12.2015": 6}

for k in sorted(d, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%d.%m.%Y")):
    print(k, d[k])
```

Output:

```
1.12.2015 5
2.12.2015 6
4.12.2015 3
```

As per you comment if  you actually have datetime objects already then you just simply sort:

```
    for k in sorted(d):
        print(k, d[k])
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this,

```
dic={"1.12.2015":5, "4.12.2015":3, "2.12.2015":6}
k = sorted(dic, key=lambda d: map(int, d.split('.')))
for i in k:
    print i," : ",dic[i]
```

cheers!

Comment: why are you `timestamps=list(dic.keys())`?

Comment: passing timestamps as a parameter to the sorted function, in the print statement, we need to strip the dictionary as a list of only dates for sorting

Comment: Why would you have to create a list or call .keys for that matter? You can call sorted on the dictionary directly, there is no need t create an intermediary list or to call .keys.

Comment: oh yeah, we can use the dictionary only as an iterable, by default the key is considered as an iterable, thanks @PadraicCunningham

Comment: yep `sorted(dic...` and forget the timestamps