# arrange keys order in a django queryset

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-queryset

I have this Django query where I get some information from different databases, which I want to expose to the front end:

```
specifics = PageData.objects.filter(page_id__in=page_ids).values('page_id'). \
                annotate(views=Count('page_id')).                            \
                values('views', 'page__title', 'page__content_size')
```

that gives me in turn a list of dictionaries - the prompt is for `list(specifics)`:

```
[
{'page__content_size': 19438L,
  'page__title': u'Bosch Tassimo Charmy anmeldelse. Positivt: Bryggehastighed. Negativt: Placering af vandtanken.  | 96 Grader',
  'views': 5},
 […]
 {'page__content_size': 19395L,
  'page__title': u'Banwood First Go Balance Bike - studiominishop.com',
  'views': 1}
]
```

I would like to be able to **arrange** the order of the keys in each dictionary, that means in a required and specific order I am provided. The order would always be the same for each element in the list.

Is there any way to do it in Django or in Python?

Comment: What is not clear about the fact that dicts don't guarantee order?

Comment: It is clear, I was just wondering if the *does not guarantee* condition may be circumvented or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probabily need this:

> import collections
>
> OrderedDict   dict subclass that remembers the order entries were added

Documentation here:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Here you can find a full example:

https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html

```
d = collections.OrderedDict()
d['a'] = 'A'
d['b'] = 'B'
d['c'] = 'C'
d['d'] = 'D'
d['e'] = 'E'

for k, v in d.items():
    print k, v`
```

Hope this help,
Ciao!

Comment: it does exactly what I want, grazie!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually related to python. Here is the cross-reference to the same question which already answered.

[Sorting dictionary keys in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575819/sorting-dictionary-keys-in-python)

You can only get a sorted representation of the key list.

Comment: maybe I've been unclear in the explanation, I'd like to arrange the order of the keys, not sort them. And I need the dictionary, not a sorted representation. I'll update my question.

Comment: @MattiaPaterna You cannot sort the dictionary. Python internally change the order of keys when storing values.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `values_list` instead of `values`. However this returns list of `tuples` instead of list of `dictionaries` but the order is always the same in all elements.

```
specifics = PageData.objects.filter(
    page_id__in=page_ids).values('page_id').annotate(
    views=Count('page_id')).values_list(
    'views', 'page__title', 'page__content_size')
```

Values will always be in the order specified in `values_list` but a tuple instead of dictionaries.

```
[
    (5, u'Bosch Tassimo Charmy anmeldelse. Positivt: Bryggehastighed. Negativt: Placering af vandtanken.  | 96 Grader', 19438L),
     […]
    (1, u'Banwood First Go Balance Bike - studiominishop.com', 19395L)
]
```

`Python dictionary does not guarantee the order`